# Delete Duplicate rows except rows with zero and null values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim value As Integer
value = Range("B3:N1955").value
If IsEmpty(value) Or value > 0 Then
Range("B3:N1955").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=13, Header:=xlsm
Else
End If
End Sub
```

I want to delete duplicate rows value except those rows with 0 or null values. I keep getting 'Type Mismatch' error every time I run the above code. Thanks in advance.
[My ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xPPj.png)

Comment: Are you considering any one column for duplicate or entire row?

Comment: Hi @RajeshS. the entire row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple code, to delete Duplicate except rows with zero and Null.

**Edited:**

*Check the Screen Shot:*

[image]

**N.B.** *Rows is RED are duplicates, Null(blank) & Zero filled with color.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=4, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- *You may change the data range as per your need.*
- *If you feel you can use this method with Worksheet_Open event also.*

Comment: Im getting Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch.

Comment: not possible,,, **before I've posted it has been tested many times. May be something is missing** , *if you feel I can post Screen Shot also.*

Comment: Sub Duplicate()
Dim value As Integer
value = Range("B3:N1955").value
If IsEmpty(value) Or value > 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:N1955").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=13, Header:=xlNo
End If

End Sub

"I change it a little bit".

Comment: No need of these lines,, Dim value As Integer                                                       value = Range("B3:N1955").value                                                                              **Remember Data Range has Range type not Integer.**

Comment: First test as I've written and for Few row will help you to observe properly. Your data range is too large to test the code !!

Comment: Hi @Rajeshs, Its working already but I dont why it keeps deleting the other rows with zero and null values. I want to keep those rows because they have formula on it and it keeps on deleting too.

Comment: @iHateBugs, check I've uploaded the Screen Shot and did little modification in code also. As you can find the code has deleted only DUPLICATES.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @Rajeshs. Its working now. :D CHEER!

Comment: Happy to help you @iHateBugs,, keep asking, :-)